# Can i call a function from python script in c++ file?

Tags: python, c++, call

I am working on a project that's implemented by c++ and i want to use some algorithms from sklearn library. can i do something like that? i know sklearn library is for python. And if it's not possible can i call a function from python script?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: we can refer to the documentation for this one: [link](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html)

Comment: Yes, it's possible in both directions, but way too broad to explain everything here in a concise answer.